# How can i add icon to my page html

Tags: html, image, icons

I've been trying to put an icon like the picture, but I could not.
I want icon on my web page like this.

[image]

I tried to do with this code but does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943771/adding-a-favicon-to-a-static-html-page

Comment: the favicon works, but i want a icon like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt5rw.png

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/a/22007642/5699206? Perhaps the apple touch, or the sizes attribute for the favicon

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029342/favicons-best-practices

Comment: it works!! :D  thank you!