# Extracting iOS favicon from any website

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, favicon

Most websites have a favicon for iOS in the root directory such as:

https://www.apple.com/apple-touch-icon.png

However, there are a lot of websites where this doesn't work.

I want to be able to download a **large** favicon (very similar to the one Apple downloads when adding a website to your Home Screen) to my iOS app.
I don't want the smallest favicon which I could do from sites such as:

https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.google.com

[image]

My intention is not to use Open Graph either, as this gives me the wrong image. An image related to the article for example, when I just wanted the newspapers' logo.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991044/how-to-get-high-resolution-website-logo-favicon-for-a-given-url#answer-22007642

Answer (score 8):

you can [get favicons from any domain using a hidden google API](https://dev.to/derlin/get-favicons-from-any-website-using-a-hidden-google-api-3p1e)

here is Swift struct for it:

```
struct FavIcon {
    enum Size: Int, CaseIterable { case s = 16, m = 32, l = 64, xl = 128, xxl = 256, xxxl = 512 }
    private let domain: String
    init(_ domain: String) { self.domain = domain }
    subscript(_ size: Size) -> String {
        "https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=\(size.rawValue)&domain=\(domain)"
    }
}
```

then you can use it like this

```
FavIcon("apple.com")[.l]
```

you can test them yourself in preview with this SwiftUI code

```
struct TestFavIconView: View {
    let domains = "apple.com,stackoverflow.com,github.com".components(separatedBy: ",")
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(domains, id:\.self) { domain in
                Section {
                    ForEach(FavIcon.Size.allCases, id:\.rawValue) { size in
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(size.rawValue)x\(size.rawValue)").font(.footnote)
                            Spacer()
                            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: FavIcon(domain)[size]))
                        }
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text(domain)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestFavIconView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestFavIconView()
    }
}
```

[image: Favicon getter]

Answer (score 1):

Downloading a favicon from *any* website can be a little bit of a nightmare, as there are multiple "download types" where you can get a favicon from.

A lot of developers place the favicon at the root directory, with the filename of "favicon". However the file could be stored elsewhere, with the location denoted in the HTML header tags. Additionally, there may be multiple different sizes of the favicon, each one having a different "label" in the HTML header tags.

Or they might not be denoted in the HTML header tags, but it might be stored in the web application manifest JSON file, which it itself has it's filename flagged in the HTML header flag.

It can be difficult.

I created an open-source framework that takes a `URL` as an input, and gets fetches the favicon for you and returns it as a `UIImage` (if you're on iOS). You can even specify which download type you'd prefer, and which size you'd prefer. If it fails to find your preferred type, it'll fall back and search other methods before failing. You can see the GitHub project here:

https://github.com/will-lumley/FaviconFinder/

Answer (score 0):

```
yourImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=yourUrl"), 
                          placeholderImage: nil)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This downloads some favicon from Google, but it doesn't solve OP's issue which is downloading *the favicon from any website*.